# Prevent Code or Function from Executing More Than Once

Tags: php, request, execute

Is there a way to prevent a code-block or a function within a code from running more than once even if I re-execute (or reload) the PHP file?

I mean, can I restrict someone from executing a php script more than once? I can't seem to find the way to do this.

Comment: You could make the PHP file delete itself; that makes sure nobody can "reload" it. *Guaranteed to run only once.*

Comment: if you explained why you wanted this, then you would get a better answer. with out having a user control system, no way will be 100% reliable.

Comment: No, I don't just want to delete the file. I want this because I have a php script that inserts some data into a MySQL database and I don't want multiple data to be inserted as many times as the script is executed

Comment: now that you explained a little more, what you should do is check the existence in the db first.

Comment: I know I can check in the DB if the value already exists, but can I not do this without checking in the DB?

Comment: check the db with out checking the db?

Comment: Sorry for the "great comment" vote, but what I'm saying is that can I not just check if the file has already been executed once without checking in the DB if data has already been inserted? I mean, my script does a LOT of things

Comment: how? you could log it, but what's the point, you have your 'check' it's the file in the db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an app that does that.

What we did was create a table in the db called version, and stored a version number in there. When the script is ran, it compared the version number in the database with that in the php script. And perform whatever it needs to "upgrade" it to the new version, and then updates the version number in the database.

Of couse, if the version table does not exist, the code will create it and mark it as storing version zero.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use a $_SESSION variable to determine if the code has been executed. The session variable will be set until the user closes their browser. If you want to extend it further than that, you can set a cookie. Please see the following links for more details.

[Session Variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php)

[Cookies](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)

Comment: You can extend the lifetime of the session_id cookie, too. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8311320/how-to-change-the-session-timeout-in-php

Answer (score 2):

If you are using sessions, then you can set a flag in the user's session array after the code has executed:

```
function doSomething(){

   if (empty($_SESSION['completed'])){
      //Do stuff here if it has not been executed.
   }

   $_SESSION['completed'] = TRUE;
}
```

You should also check the sesison variable to see if the task has been executed previously. This assumes that the user can accept a session cookie.

Comment: That doesn't prevent repeated calls on the command line via `$ php thescript.php` from executing the function over and over. The OP's question is just *very* unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Just put a counter in the function. If the counter is greater that 0, then don't do anything. The counter variable should be static so it "remembered" across multiple calls.

```
function sample() {
     static $call_counter = 0;
     if ( $call_counter>0 ) {
         return;
     }
     ...
     $call_counter++;
 }
```

As for making sure a file is only executed once, just use "include_once()" instead of "include()".

Comment: This will not prevent the code from being executed if the page is reloaded.

Comment: Indeed, this won't prevent the code from being executed twice because every time you run the script (reload the php file), your $call_counter will be set to 0

Comment: If declared static, it only gets set the first time the function is called. Subsequent calls remember the last value. Read example #5 http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: The "first time the function is called" _during the same page load_. So in the context of a webpage being reloaded, this is indeed false. The same way it is false in case of a PHP script being executed a second time in a console by the way.